# По каким причинам удаляется не тот элемент в массиве?

Tags: javascript, slider

Доброй ночи, пишу зацикленный слайдер (пока что, как "черновик", т.к не доделан). План такой: добавляю в массив три `picture` (в моем примере так, но можно и больше), потом удаляю из `html`, после с помощью функции создаю два `picture`, которые первый видимый, второй правее от него(сл. слайд). Первый `picture` из видимых в `html` должен удалится, второй сместиться на его место, а перед вторым создаться третий по клику (сейчас, но потом `setInterval`). И так всё по кругу. Но проблема в том, что удаляется не тот массив, хотя текст, который находится внутри `picture` функционирует, как часы. Посмотрите лучше код (в теге `picture` сейчас просто фон, но будут картинки, а текст анимирован, когда слайд попадет в "активную зону"):

HTML:

```
<header>
    <figure class="header-slider">
        <picture class="slides">
            <span>
                <h1>Hello page 1</h1>
                <p>About page one</p>
            </span>
        </picture>

        <picture class="slides">
            <span>
                <h1>Hello page 2</h1>
                <p>About page two</p>
            </span>
        </picture>

        <picture class="slides">
            <span>
                <h1>Hello page 3</h1>
                <p>About page three</p>
            </span>
        </picture>
    </figure>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    display: block;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    width: 100%; height: 100vh;
}

    .header-slider {
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .slides {
            display: flex; text-align: center;
            width: 100%; height: 100%;
            position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
            transition: 600ms ease;
        }

        .slides:nth-of-type(1) {
            background: yellow;
        }

        .slides:nth-of-type(2) {
            background: red;
        }

        .slides:nth-of-type(3) {
            background: blue;
        }

            .slides span {
                margin: auto;
            }
```

JS:

```
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
let slide = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        slide[i] = slides[i];
        slide[i].remove();
    }

let step = 0;
let offset = 0;

    function create() {
        let picture = document.createElement('picture');
        picture = slide[step];
        picture.classList.add('slides');
        picture.style.left = offset * 100 + '%';
        document.querySelector('.header-slider').appendChild(picture);
        if(step + 1 == slide.length){
            step = 0;
        }else{
            step++;
        }
        offset = 1;
    }

function move(){
    document.onclick = null;
    let viewSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
    let offset2 = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < viewSlides.length; i++){
            viewSlides[i].style.left = offset2 * 100 - 100 + '%';
            offset2++;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            create();
            viewSlides[0].remove();
            document.onclick = move;
        }, 1000)
}

create();create();
document.onclick = move;
```

Если запустить код, то при нажатии в любом месте документа, желтый блок с надписью "Hello page 1" должен сместиться влево, и удалиться после 1с, красный встать в центр с надписью "Hello page 2", а при повторном клике, красный сместиться влево + создаться новый `picture` с надписью "Hello page 3". На очередной клик, синий блок влево, создается все по новой: желтый блок, красный, синий и т.д.

Почему удаляется не тот блок? Удаляется следующий (красный блок), а не желтый, хотя должен он удалиться.

На всякий случай, вот здесь можно посмотреть работу слайдера. https://jsfiddle.net/qbdvw10t/
Прокрутите вниз в окне, там что-то не так, но слайдер рабочий.

Comment: что-то не получается воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Удаляется правильный слайд. Скорее всего вас вводит в замешательство цвета ваших блоков, синий никогда не появится из-за особенностей вашего `css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаляется правильный слайд.

Скорее всего вас вводит в замешательство цвета ваших блоков, синий никогда не появится из-за особенностей вашего `css`, а именно селектора `.slides:nth-of-type(3)`.

```js
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
let slide = [];

for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slide[i] = slides[i];
  slide[i].remove();
}

let step = 0;
let offset = 0;

function create() {
  let picture = document.createElement('div');
  picture = slide[step];
  picture.dataset.step = step; // указываем позицию
  picture.classList.add('slides');
  picture.style.left = offset * 100 + '%';
  document.querySelector('.header-slider').appendChild(picture);
  if (step + 1 == slide.length) {
    step = 0;
  } else {
    step++;
  }
  offset = 1;
}

function move() {
  document.onclick = null;
  let viewSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
  let offset2 = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < viewSlides.length; i++) {
    viewSlides[i].style.left = offset2 * 100 - 100 + '%';
    offset2++;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    create();
    viewSlides[0].remove();
    document.onclick = move;
  }, 1000)
}

create();
create();
document.onclick = move;
```

```css
* {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

style,
script {
  display: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 600ms ease;
}

.slides[data-step="0"] {
  background: yellow;
}

.slides[data-step="1"] {
  background: red;
}

.slides[data-step="2"] {
  background: blue;
}

.slides span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <figure class="header-slider">
    <picture class="slides">
      <span>
                <h1>Hello page 1</h1>
                <p>About page one</p>
            </span>
    </picture>

    <picture class="slides">
      <span>
                <h1>Hello page 2</h1>
                <p>About page two</p>
            </span>
    </picture>

    <picture class="slides">
      <span>
                <h1>Hello page 3</h1>
                <p>About page three</p>
            </span>
    </picture>
  </figure>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо............

Comment: Простите, могу ли я как-то добавить его для двух-трех разделов на сайте, но для других использовать не left, а допустим bottom (изменить направления слайда) не повторяя код? Наверно  таком случае его потребуется полностью изменить?

Comment: Данный код придется модифицировать, что бы можно было применить его к нескольким слайдерам на странице. Он не совсем универсален.